# Unfreeze layers of models on GluonCV

Tags: yolo, faster-rcnn, mxnet-gluon

I'm using Faster-RCNN, Yolo, and SSD models on GluonCV (mxnet) to predict on some medical images. However, the training result isn't ideal because the number of images in the dataset is small. As a result, I decide to use transfer learning and unfreeze the output layer with the 'reset_class' method to train my models. But the result is still below expectation. Thus, I'm trying to unfreeze more layers to improve the accuracy of the training result, but I couldn't find any build-in function to achieve this.

Basically, I have two questions as follow:
First, is it possible to unfreeze more layers on GluonCV?
Second, if not, is there any other way that I could use to further improve the accuracy of my result?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why you believe that model parameters are frozen by default and `reset_class` will unfreeze an output layer. Still, if you want to unfreeze specific parameters, you need to choose them with `collect_params` method and set their `grad_req` attribute to `'write'`. For example, having the following convolutional network

```py
import mxnet as mx

class ConvNet(mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential):
    def __init__(self, n_classes, params=None, prefix=None):
        super().__init__(params=params, prefix=prefix)

        self.features = mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential()
        self.features.add(mx.gluon.nn.Conv2D(channels=6, kernel_size=5, padding=2,
                          activation='relu'))
        self.add(mx.gluon.nn.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
        self.add(mx.gluon.nn.Flatten())

        self.output = mx.gluon.nn.Dense(units=n_classes)

    def hybrid_forward(self, F, x):
        x = self.features(x)
        return self.output(x)

net = ConvNet(10)
```

you can unfreeze convolution (features) block with

```py
net.features.collect_params().setattr('grad_req', 'write')
```

Also, if your model is not composed of `features`, `output`, and/or other separate blocks (e.g. it's a single sequential block):

```py
net = mx.gluon.nn.HybridSequential()
net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Conv2D(channels=6, kernel_size=5, padding=2,
                           activation='relu'))
net.add(mx.gluon.nn.MaxPool2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Flatten())
net.add(mx.gluon.nn.Dense(units=10))
```

to unfreeze the convolution block try this:

```py
net.collect_params('conv*').setattr('grad_req', 'write')
```